# how to insert a word in text file using shell script

Tags: shell

Can any one please help me for below problem

I have a text file in below format and i want to insert a word in a specific field and i want to save that file in shell script with out disturb any thing in the file.

Ex:

```
cat sample.txt

name=xxxxxx

age=45

gender=femal

college=XXXXXX

class=b1

section=h2
```

like that

I want to insert in place of XXXXX some word.

Is it possible or not ?

Comment: Certainly that is possible. There are millions of possibilities. You might want to take a look at the utilities `sed` and `awk`... Also reading a bit about regular expressions and their application in text processing would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/college=.*/college=SOME WORD/' sample.txt
```

Comment: +1; generalization with backreferences: `sed -i 's/\(college=\).*/\1SOME WORD/' sample.txt`; OSX users: use `-i ''` instead of just `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
sed -i '/^college=/ccollege=some word' sample.txt
```

Result

```
name=xxxxxx

age=45

gender=femal

college=some word

class=b1

section=h2
```

Comment: OSX users: use `sed -i '' '/^college=/c\'$'\n''college=some word' sample.txt` - `sed` there requires the `-i` option to always have an argument and requires the `c` command to be followed by a `\ ` and a literal newline before specifying the output string.